# Regex for matching thematic breaks in markdown

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I'm trying to make a RegEx that matches all thematic breaks in a string for use in JavaScript's `String.split` function.

A thematic break can be:

- Hyphens: `---`
- Asterisks: `***`
- Underscores: `___`

Can have whitespace between the hyphens, asterisks or underscores, but you can't mix-n-match, for example this is not valid `--*`.

Full spec: https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#thematic-breaks

Here's what I've tried: `/[-*_]{3,}/g` but that does not match ones with whitespace in the middle, if I add a space there it will match stuff like `--`  which is not desirable. I also thought of first striping the whitespace but I'd like to fit it all into a RegEx.

Is this possible? And how?

Comment: `All possible mutations` ... your question needs to stand on its own two feet.  Please include sample data along with your current JS code.

Comment: Your regex will match 3 DIFFERENT characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[ ]{0,3}([-*_])\s*\1\s*\1+\s*$/gm
```

**Explanation**:

`^` - match start of line

`[ ]{0,3}` - match optional up to 3 spaces

`([-*_])` - match either `-`, `*` or `_` and put it in a group

`\s*\1\s*\1+\s*` - match optional white spaces and the character from the first group twice

`$` - match end of line

**Edit** (from comment):

```
/^[ ]{0,3}([-*_])\s*(?:\1\s*){2,}$/gm
```

It now supports repeated patterns as long as the character used is the same.

This group:

`(?:\1\s*)` is repeated 2 or more times.

Examples of matches:

```
***
  - - -                   
 __            _
 ** * ** * ** * **
```

Examples of non matches:

```
*-_
abc
          +++
```

I should add that I use `\s` although the spec says 'space or tab'. Since this must be parsed line by line, `\s` should be safe.

You can test the regex [here.](https://bak-o-soft.dk/RegExp/JSRegExpBuilder/UmpKTg)

Comment: but shouldn't this be matched as well ` **  * ** * ** * **`? Ex#52 from the https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#thematic-breaks

Comment: @star67: You're right, thanks. Have updated.